# why my while loop doesn't work in Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

please click the link to view the images.

[I have a Json Extractor, which saves the value returned in "status"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVZK8.png)

[it's working:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLeaM.png)

[and I also have a "Controller while" with this condition:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfNh1.png)

$ {__ javaScript ("${status}". indexOf ("string") != 500 ,)}

But something strange is happening

***2021-11-25 14:30:46,258 DEBUG o.a.j.c.WhileController: Condition string: '$ {__ javaScript ("ERROR". indexOf ("string") != 500 ,)}'***
**2021-11-25 14:30:46,258 DEBUG o.a.j.c.WhileController: Condition value: 'false'**
2021-11-25 14:30:46,258 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function

***Wasn't it supposed to give "true" and end the loop?***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please don't use images for code, data structures or log files](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9078341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is not very correct, if you want to end the loop when your `${status}` variable becomes `500` you should use something like:

```
${__javaScript("${status}" != "500",)}
```

Also from performance perspective it's better to consider using [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

```
${__jexl3("${status}" != "500",)}
```

or [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get("status") != "500",)}
```

as this is something that [__javaScript() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) suggests

[image]

Comment: I had done it like this:

${__javaScript("${status}" == "500",)}

right after posting here, because I saw that I should leave the String in quotes, and also because I want it to run while it's ==500 and stop when it's different but this code of mine doesn't even execute the request

Comment: When JMeter checks whether it should enter the While Controller it evaluates the condition and given your `status` variable is not defined yet JMeter compares `${status}` to `500` and since it does give `false` it doesn't enter the While Controller. In order to make your current implementation working you need to give this `status` variable the value of `500` somewhere somehow before the While loop, for example you can go for [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)

Comment: wow, thank you so much man. You helped me a lot.